# Unlikely argument type for equals(): String seems to be unrelated to Scanner

Tags: java, types, arguments, equals

Unlikely argument type for equals(): String seems to be unrelated to Scanner. why appear like this: [image: here]

Answer (score 1):

You're checking if your Scanner object is equal to a string. What you need to do is take input using the Scanner with `scan.NextLine()` which will return a string with the input value from the console, then compare against that.

```
String userInput = scan1.NextLine();
if(userInput.equals("Harimau"))
   ...etc
```